# How can I temporarily "block" an EventStream in bacon.js using another stream?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frp, bacon.js

I'm trying to wrap my head around FRP concepts and build an image slider using `bacon.js`. I'm mapping the `next` button's (this is a contrived example btw) click stream like:

```
var position = $slideshow.find('.next').asEventStream('click').map(function(){
    return 1;
}).scan(0, function(x,y){
    return x + y < $slideshow.find('.slide').length ? (x + y) : 0;
});

position.onValue(function(val){
    //set things
});
```

This works fine. Now I would like to disable clicking of my slideshow while it is advancing to the next slide. All ways that I could think of include the creation of a state variable that I feed to `skipWhile` like:

```
var isAnimating = false;
var position = $slideshow.find('.next').asEventStream('click').map(function(){
    return 1;
}).skipWhile(isAnimating).scan(0, function(x,y){
    return x + y < $slideshow.find('.slide').length ? (x + y) : 0;
});

position.onValue(function(val){
    isAnimating = true;
    //set things
});
```

This feels like cheating (especially when doing FRP "excercises"...) so I was wondering if there is any way I could combine my click stream with a stream of animation end events:

```
var animationEndStream = $slideshow.asEventStream('animationend');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you manage to capture animation end events as an `EventStream`, say `animEndE`, you can now define the "is animating" state as a `Property` as in

```
var animEndE = $slideshow.asEventStream('animationend')
var nextE = $slideshow.find('.next').asEventStream('click')
var prevE = $slideshow.find('.next').asEventStream('click')
var moveE = nextE.map(1).merge(prevE.map(-1))

var animatingP = moveE.awaiting(animEndE)
var position = moveE.filter(animatingP.not()).scan(0, function(x,y) { return x+y })
```

As you can see, I'm filtering the `moveE` stream based on the negation of `animatingP`.